# Compiling QT from Source depends to original src directory

Tags: qt

I am compiling QT 5.9 from Source code. There was no problem to build the library as its manual says.

The problem is it generates header files that are linked to parents of the `src` directory in the original source code directory structure. For example, `qdebug.h` contains this code:

```
#include "../../../../5.9/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qdebug.h"
```

but it should be this line:

```
#include "../../src/corelib/io/qdebug.h"
```

I used this command line to do the configuration:

```
configure.bat -prefix C:\qt\Qt5.9x86 -debug-and-release -static
```

I want to generate QT headers and libs in separate directory that does not depend on src directory anymore, as the QT Installer does. In this way I cannot delete original source code any more.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're asking here... because you're not actually asking anything. Not clear how this is a problem for you, or what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my fault! After making the projects I should execute `nmake install` or `jom install` ! After that it will generate the correct include files and Libs in prefix directory.